# How to prevent call to a WCF Service made from Silverlight client from getting timed out

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, silverlight

I need to send about 10,000 rows of data to a WCF service which in turn inserts it into a database one by one. This process takes more than 1 hour. But, as soon as 1 hour is completed from begining of operation, I get a service not found exception which I believe is due to some time out.
However, service continues to insert this data into database as long as the visual studio development server keeps running.

I have tried setting all the time out values to 2 hours both on client side and servcie side but it doesn't help.

***web.config for service:***

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDService" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="02:00:00"
                         openTimeout="02:00:00" receiveTimeout="02:00:00" sendTimeout="02:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None"/>

        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

***On client side(while initializing the serviceclient)***

```
    this.binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
    this.binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
    this.binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
    this.binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);

    this.binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    this.binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
```

I did some search and at many places it was suggested to increase OperationTimeout. So I tried it but without any success.

```
((IContextChannel)base.Channel).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
```

Please give some idea about what should I try so that service completes entire operation and sends back a response to client.
Also, let me know if you think there is a better approach to do this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options that you can try:

1. Start writting in a different thread.

This way you can respond faster, telling that the data has been received successfully.
Then you can ask the service if the data has been written yet - you might even be able to respond with how much have been written until now.
At last you can get the response.

1. Only send a few records at a time.

This way you can respond faster and you can show the progress.

1. Optimize writting.

Two hours are a huge amount of time for writting only 10000 records.
Maybe you should take a look at SqlBulkCopy and combine it with a DataTable, this can improve speed considerable, but can only be used for insert.

You can combine 1 and 2 with number 3.

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I can definitely try 2nd and 3rd straight away. However, 1st point is not very clear to me. Do you imply making use of duplex binding to let service send multiple responses?

Comment: Also I wonder why does the operation break at exactly one hour from start.

Comment: First is sending the records (as before), the service return "data received, I am working on it, you can get the status using this id".  Then you can request the status with the id (status could be how many records have been written etc.).  When status done you could ask for the result with that id.  It is a little more complicated, but having a timeout for several hours is not a good method.

Answer (score 1):

I think your web service endpoint got killed because it did not respond to the app server in reasonable time. Second thing I would notice, you do something on a web service side for more than 2 hours. Not good solution at all.

In case if you process the data before save:

I sugest that you store all the data somewhere in DB and having another one Watchdog or "Job" or "Queue manager" Proess to get this job done in the background.

If this is not a case then I have a question:

Why does it take 2 hours to get the data saved?

Comment: Thanks..I agree its not a very good solution to have to wait for 2 hours. But I am making use of a legacy app which is doing the job writing into DB after some processing. But one thing is still not clear to me is why does the operation break at exactly 1 hour from start..